# Are there HDDs that have better quality materials(eg,magnets etc) than others?

Tags: hard-drive

Are there HDDs brands/models, that have better quality materials(eg,magnets etc)that are supposed to last longer ,than others?

Comment: A good indicator is the included warranty. Other than that, you question is largely opinion-based.

Comment: There is much information on the web on *disk failure rate* by model and brand, e.g. https://www.backblaze.com/blog/backblaze-hard-drive-stats-q1-2021/ and https://platinumdatarecovery.com/blog/which-hard-drive-brand-is-the-most-reliable . However, any broad statement is a matter of opinion -- and authors may have an axe to grind -- and does not belong here.

Comment: I am voting to reopen.  This is not an opinion based answer.  It has a definite yes or no answer.  Now it is a question of whether or not someone has evidence to prove the answer one way or another .

Answer (score 1):

This has become a bit of a difficult question.

First, if you need a hard drive, get the best you can and with a 2 or 3 year warranty.

Second, hard drives as a user, consumer, small business strategy are dying out. Why?  Good quality SSD Drives with (say) 600 TB Written Capacity are coming down in price, are quieter, use lees power and do not cause traditional hard drive rotation vibration. What's not to like.

So it seems to me based on experience and some research that engineering design and effort is going more into SSD technology and less into Hard Drive technology because a big market is drying up inexorably.

Sata SSD drives in an adapter can replace most hard drives in a modern machine.

My Desktop computers (one now out of service, one new) are or have been SSD for 2 to 3 years. My laptop has a good fast NVMe drive.

So all of this is to say that use care in buying a hard drive today and make sure it is good quality. Cheap hard drives will die a quick death in a lot of cases.

For someone viewing, I am not talking about large very high quality commercial hard drives for servers and like applications.

Answer (score 1):

In theory yes.  Server grade hard drives are have higher Mean Time Before Failure ([MTBF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_time_between_failures)).  They are manufactured to be constantly online and be read from and written to, as opposed to desktop hard drives.  Server grade SATA drives typically use Serial Attached SCSI [SAS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serial_Attached_SCSI) drives and connectors, rather than normal SATA.  I dont know how much of a difference there is between the server and commercial grade drive manufacturing, but there definitely is a cost and warranty difference.